# FosUserBundle Registration, which saves data into 2 different tables

Tags: symfony, entity, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserbundle in symfony 3 and want to use a second table, 
where I save the address data.

Therefore I use the extended User Entity and the addresses Entity.

Workflow:

f.e. `first_name,last_name,company` and all other `Formdata` should go to **md_user** table.

copy of `first_name,last_name,company` etc should go to **md_addresses** table, which has got the "**customer_id**" field of **md_user.id**

To get it working I use the `Eventlistener` in `RegistrationType`:

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
```

and the method:

```
 public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getData();
    $user->addAddress(new Addresses());
    $event->setData($user);

}
```

Before I use `$event->setData($user)` in `RegistrationType`, the `$user` looks like:

[image]

My Questions are:

1) How to get the back the field **id** of md_user from doctrine

2) How to save the other data with this id to md_addresses

Thats what I have done right now.

User Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;


 class User extends BaseUser
{

   /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Different Logins for One Customer
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_id",type="integer",nullable=true,options={"default":null})
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Addresses", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     **/
    protected $customer_id;

    /**
      * @var \DateTime
      * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
      */
     protected $created;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="mandant",type="integer")
      */
    protected $mandant;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(name="salutation", type="string", length=1)
      */
     protected $salutation;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=120)
      * @Assert\Length(
      *     min=2,
      *     max=120,
      *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
      *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
      *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
      * )
      */
     protected $first_name;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
      * @Assert\Length(
      *     min=2,
      *     max=255,
      *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
      *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
      *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
      * )
      */
     protected $last_name;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(name="company", type="string", length=255)
      */
     protected $company;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", type="string", length=150)
      */
     protected $street;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", type="string", length=30)
      */
     protected $street_number;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", type="string", length=150)
      */
     protected $city;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", type="string", length=150)
      */
     protected $plz;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(name="ustid", type="string", length=30)
      */
     protected $ustid;

     /**
      * @var string
      * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=6)
      */
     protected $country;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="telephone",type="string",length=120)
      */
     protected $telephone;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="email_info", type="string",length=255,nullable=true)
      */
     protected $email_info;
     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="email_invoice", type="string",length=255,nullable=true)
      */
     protected $email_invoice;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="send_info", type="boolean",nullable=true)
      */
     protected $send_info = true;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="invoice_pdf", type="boolean",nullable=true)
      */
     protected $invoice_pdf = true;

     /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Addresses", mappedBy="customer_id", cascade={"persist","remove"})
      */
     protected $addresses;
     /**
      * @var bool
      * @ORM\Column(name="newsletter", type="boolean")
      */
     protected $newsletter=true;


     public function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->created         = new \DateTime();
//         $this->addresses              = new ArrayCollection();
     }


     /**
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function getEmailInfo()
     {
         return $this->email_info;
     }

     public function setEmailInfo($email_info)
     {
         $this->email_info = is_null($email_info) ? $this->email : $email_info;
         return $this;
     }

     public function getEmailInvoice()
     {
         return $this->email_invoice;
     }

     /**
      * @param mixed $email_invoice
      * @return User
      */
     public function setEmailInvoice($email_invoice)
     {
         $this->email_invoice = is_null($email_invoice) ? $this->email : $email_invoice;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function getInvoicePdf()
     {
         return $this->invoice_pdf;
     }

     /**
      * @param mixed $invoice_pdf
      * @return User
      */
     public function setInvoicePdf($invoice_pdf)
     {
         $this->invoice_pdf = $invoice_pdf;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function getSendInfo()
     {
         return $this->send_info;
     }

     /**
      * @param mixed $send_info
      * @return User
      */
     public function setSendInfo($send_info)
     {
         $this->send_info = $send_info;
         return $this;
     }





     public function getTelephone()
     {
         return $this->telephone;
     }

     /**
      * @param mixed $telephone
      * @return User
      */
     public function setTelephone($telephone)
     {
         $this->telephone = $telephone;
         return $this;
     }


     public function setEmail($email)
     {
         $email = is_null($email) ? '' : $email;
         parent::setEmail($email);
         $this->setUsername($email);
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getSalutation()
     {
         return $this->salutation;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $saluation
      * @return User
      */
     public function setSalutation($salutation)
     {
         $this->salutation = $salutation;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getFirstName()
     {
         return $this->first_name;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $first_name
      * @return User
      */
     public function setFirstName($first_name)
     {

         $this->first_name = $first_name;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getLastName()
     {
         return $this->last_name;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $last_name
      * @return User
      */
     public function setLastName($last_name)
     {
         $this->last_name = $last_name;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getCompany()
     {
         return $this->company;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $company
      * @return User
      */
     public function setCompany($company)
     {
         $this->company = $company;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getUstid()
     {
         return $this->ustid;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $ustid
      * @return User
      */
     public function setUstid($ustid)
     {
         $this->ustid = $ustid;
         return $this;
     }


     public function getName()
     {
         return 'user';
     }

     /**
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function getMandant()
     {
         return $this->mandant;
     }

     /**
      * @param mixed $mandant
      * @return User
      */
     public function setMandant($mandant)
     {
         $this->mandant = $mandant;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getCity()
     {
         return $this->city;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $city
      * @return User
      */
     public function setCity($city)
     {
         $this->city = $city;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getCountry()
     {
         return $this->country;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $country
      * @return User
      */
     public function setCountry($country)
     {
         $this->country = $country;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getStreet()
     {
         return $this->street;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $street
      * @return User
      */
     public function setStreet($street)
     {
         $this->street = $street;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getStreetNumber()
     {
         return $this->street_number;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $street_number
      * @return User
      */
     public function setStreetNumber($street_number)
     {
         $this->street_number = $street_number;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return string
      */
     public function getPlz()
     {
         return $this->plz;
     }

     /**
      * @param string $plz
      * @return User
      */
     public function setPlz($plz)
     {
         $this->plz = $plz;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Set created
      *
      * @param \DateTime $created
      *
      * @return User
      */
     public function setCreated($created)
     {
         $this->created = $created;

         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Get created
      *
      * @return \DateTime
      */
     public function getCreated()
     {
         return $this->created;
     }



     /**
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function getCustomerId()
     {
         return $this->customer_id;
     }

     /**
      * @param mixed $customer_id
      * @return User
      */
     public function setCustomerId($customer_id)
     {
         $this->customer_id = $customer_id;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * @return mixed
      */
     public function getId()
     {
         return $this->id;
     }

     /**
      * Set newsletter
      * @param boolean $newsletter
      * @return User
      */
     public function setNewsletter($newsletter)
     {
         $this->newsletter = $newsletter;

         return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Get newsletter
      * @return bool
      */
     public function getNewsletter()
     {
         return $this->newsletter;
     }

     /**
      * Add professional
      *
      * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Addresses $addresses
      *
      * @return User
      */
     public function addAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Addresses $addresses)
     {
         $addresses->setSalutation($this->salutation);
         $addresses->setFirstName($this->first_name);
         $addresses->setLastName($this->last_name);
         $addresses->setEmail($this->email);
         $addresses->setTelephone($this->telephone);
         $addresses->setStreet($this->street);
         $addresses->setStreetNumber($this->street_number);
         $addresses->setPlz($this->plz);
         $addresses->setCity($this->city);
         $addresses->setCountry($this->country);
         $addresses->setCompany($this->company);
         $addresses->setInvoice(true);
         $addresses->setDelivery(true);
         $addresses->setCustomerId($this->id);
         return $this->addresses = $addresses;
     }
     /**
      * Get addresses
      *
      * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
      */
     public function getAddresses()
     {
         return $this->addresses;
     }

     public function getFullName()
     {
         return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
     }
 }
```

Addresses Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;



/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="md_addresses")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AddressesRepository")
 */


class Addresses
{
    /**
     * @var id

     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="addresses", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $customer_id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="salutation", type="string",length=1)
     */
    protected $salutation;
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=120)
     */

    protected $first_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     */

    protected $last_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephone",type="string",length=120)
     */
    protected $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email",type="string",length=255)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="company", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    protected $street_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $additional_1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $additional_2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $additional_3;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    protected $plz;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */

    protected $country;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":true})
     */

    protected $invoice;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":true})
     */

    protected $sender;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":true})
     */
    protected $delivery;




      /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSalutation()
    {
        return $this->salutation;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $salutation
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setSalutation($salutation)
    {
        $this->salutation = $salutation;
        return $this;
    }



    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $company
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setCompany($company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $street
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStreetNumber()
    {
        return $this->street_number;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $street_number
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setStreetNumber($street_number)
    {
        $this->street_number = $street_number;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdditional1()
    {
        return $this->additional_1;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $additional_1
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setAdditional1($additional_1)
    {
        $this->additional_1 = $additional_1;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdditional2()
    {
        return $this->additional_2;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $additional_2
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setAdditional2($additional_2)
    {
        $this->additional_2 = $additional_2;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdditional3()
    {
        return $this->additional_3;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $additional_3
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setAdditional3($additional_3)
    {
        $this->additional_3 = $additional_3;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlz()
    {
        return $this->plz;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $plz
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setPlz($plz)
    {
        $this->plz = $plz;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $city
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $country
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInvoice()
    {
        return $this->invoice;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $invoice
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setInvoice($invoice)
    {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSender()
    {
        return $this->sender;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $sender
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setSender($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDelivery()
    {
        return $this->delivery;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $delivery
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setDelivery($delivery)
    {
        $this->delivery = $delivery;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Set user
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setCustomerId(\AppBundle\Entity\User $customer_id = null)
    {
        $this->customer_id = $customer_id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->customer_id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $first_name
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setFirstName($first_name)
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $last_name
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setLastName($last_name)
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTelephone()
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $telephone
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setTelephone($telephone)
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     * @return Addresses
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }



}
```

RegistrationType:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{

    private $session;
    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);


        $builder ->add('salutation', SalutationType::class,
                        array('placeholder'   => 'form.choice'))
                 ->add('telephone',     TextType::class,array('required' => false))
                 ->remove('username')
                 ->add('first_name',    TextType::class)
                 ->add('mandant',    HiddenType::class,array('data'=>$this->session->get('mandantId')))
                 ->add('last_name',     TextType::class)
                 ->add('company',       TextType::class,array('required' => false))
                 ->add('street',         TextType::class)
                 ->add('street_number',  TextType::class)
                 ->add('ustid',         TextType::class,array('required' => false))
                 ->add('plz', TextType::class)
                 ->add('city', TextType::class)
                 ->add('newsletter',CheckboxType::class,array('label' => false,'required' => false))
                 ->add('country', CountryType::class, [
                    'required' => true,
                    'placeholder' => 'form.choice',
                    'preferred_choices' => [
                        'DE', 'NL', 'BE', 'CH', 'AUT',
                    ]])
                  ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));



    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getData();
        $user->addAddress(new Addresses());

        $event->setData($user);

    }

    public function getParent()

    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()

    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()

    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
class RegistrationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => [
                ['onRegistrationSuccess']
                ],
            ];
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $address = new Address();
        $address->setSalutation($user->getSalutation());
        $address->setFirstName($user->getFirstName());
        $address->setLastName($user->getLastName());
        $address->setEmail($user->getEmail());
        $address->setTelephone($user->getTelephone());
        $address->setStreet($user->getStreet());
        $address->setStreetNumber($user->getStreetNumber());
        $address->setPlz($user->getPlz());
        $address->setCity($user->getCity());
        $address->setCountry($user->getCountry());
        $address->setCompany($user->getCompany());
        $address->setCustomerId($user->getId());
        $user->addAddress($address);
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I am using FOSUserbundle in symfony 3 and want to use a second database, where I save the addressdata.`
Another table or another database

Comment: If I 'm getting this right you want to save some of the input to another table ?
You have a user entity with many addresses and an entity addresses .
If that's the case it's pretty simple

Comment: Sorry. Yes you are Right. It should be table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Greg said it's easy to get the `id` from doctrine through the `FOSUserBundle`

Now, for the second part I would suggest you use a  `Collection`
In your `User` entity add an `ArrayCollection` property for your addresses.
And declare the methods to add a new collection to the `user` object.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * User
 */
class User
{

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $addresses;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->addresses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add address
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $address
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->addresses[] = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove address
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $address
     */
    public function removeAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->addresses->removeElement($address);
    }

    /**
     * Get addresses
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getAddresses()
    {
        return $this->addresses;
    }


}
```

Now when you create a new `User` you can call the `addAddresses` method to add a new `address`.

Example:

```
$user = new User;
$address = new Address;
... // copy of first_name,last_name,company to the address object

$address->setLastName($user->getLastName()); // or whatever field you want
$user->addAddress($address); 

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Now you call the `$user->getAddresses()` method, and get all the addresses.

Comment: This will only work if you either explicitly persist the address entity before you save the user entity or configure cascade persist in the underlying association mapping.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How to get the back the field id of md_user from doctrine

Your user entity will automatically get an id when it' s stored in database. You can get it's id with the appropriate getter. This said, you will have to listen to an event, which occurs after the entity was stored in db. I would recommend to rely on FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS or FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED. See the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html) for it's proper usage. You can then access your regsitered user via

```
 $user = $event->getUser();
```

> 2) How to save the other data with this id to md_addresses

You create a new address entity, set the desired data including the user to which the address belongs to. Then persist and flush this entity to your db.

Code sample:

```
$address = new Address();
$address->setFirstname = $user->getFirstname();
$address->setUser($user);
$em->persist($address);
$em->flush();
```